# Overriding all core files to local in Magento

Tags: magento

I want upgrade my magento version from `1.5` to `1.7.0.2`. But my previous team member has done code in many core files. So it is difficult to upgrade. For this we decided to copy all files from core to local with same folder structure to override

like

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales         to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/Backup        to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog       to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout      to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts      to /app/code/local/Mage

/app/code/core/Mage/Reports       to /app/code/local/Mage
```

Is this a correct way?
Will this affect the performance of the Magento site?

Comment: In for a world 'a hurt...

Answer (score 4):

The reason that it is better to use observers and class rewrites rather than core modifications (whether direct or via include path) is because there is rarely a need to override an *entire* class definition. While the latter methods are simply more painful/more work, **regardless of how prior customization was implemented *you must merge past changes with new functionality***. This is true of any software upgrade.

Be a professional: run a diff against a vanilla 1.5.x.x codebase and merge changes out of the core as much as possible. At the very least only move to *app/code/local/Mage/* those classes which have significantly changed or which are superclasses, and then diff those against their 1.7.0.2 version to complete the merge.

Note that any resource models which have been changed in the core (typically under *Mysql4* folders) *must* be adapted via rewrite or ported to their *Resource*-path counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

/app/code/core/Mage/Sales to /app/code/local/ProjectName/Rewrites/

and your structure could look like:
app/
  code/
 
    local/
      ProjectName/
         Rewrites/
           Block/
           etc/
           Helper/
           Model/

Another solution for you is use PHPStorm and do it through the program. Once you set up the project, open the files and press ALT + M to rewrite it into whatever folder you want. Also the Program creates the xml's files any anything else you need.

Easy and simple.

I hope I've helped in somehow.

Comment: Is this solution affect the site performance ?
copy all files from core to local with same folder structure to override

Comment: Vaibhav, as you might know Magento is a configurableMVC. It means all the configuration is loaded through the XML's files and once one class is overwritten the new one is loaded instead. It doesn't affect the Margento's performance, behaving on the same way as any module available in the community. And Magento is slow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You already said it, your predecessor made upgrading difficult with his core hacks. You should not worry about performance, code in app/code/local does not affect it negatively. But you should worry about function, because lots of code from different versions will most likely not work well together.

What you suggest is the first step of cleaning up, but the next step should not be the update.

1. Move core hacks to app/code/local
2. Convert them to modules, using class rewrites if necessary but always prefer observers. Rewrites should not be changed copies of the original but extend them and override as little as possible.
3. update Magento
4. Adapt rewritten classes for new version

After every step the system should be tested thoroughly, automate as much of that as possible.

Step 4 should not be much because 1.7 is backwards compatible to 1.5 in most parts.

It's a lot of work but this is the technical dept that you inherited and with the update comes payday.
The most complicated thing in this process is finding out what the core hacks do, which belong together and if they are really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to do a diff on the 1.5.xx version against stock core unmodified code, write modules to reflect the changes and then upgrade to 1.7.xx.

`diff -qrbB app/unmodified-core app/modified-core`

Will allow you to find all the evil. The modules then will only need the functions that have been changed, which may be far less than you realize. Since it is a handful of functions, you will actually have far less headache on the upgrade as there is a lot less code out there to conflict (potentially everything you copy to local/Mage is going to clash with core/Mage in your proposed method) making troubleshooting problems after the module writes like finding a needle in a cup of sugar instead of a barn full of hay.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer

I want to share what i did.

First i download fresh 1.5 magento version. Then i compare the code in my /app/code/core/Mage with fresh 1.5 magento /app/code/core/Mage with the help of tool like Meld Diff Viewer in linux. then i override the files in local folder in which i found difference.

2nd step : Upgrade the database with Magento 1.7. To upgrade the database, enter the credential of 1.5 database (username, password,dbname) in app/etc/local.xml of 1.7 magento. Run the 1.7 magento installation. check the database tables, after database upgradation , number of table are increases.

3rd step : upload the files(/app/code/core/ , js folder, includes folder and lib folder) of magento 1.7 to 1.5

4th step : Disabled local module.

5: Delete cache folder.

1. Check the site , and enable local module one by one.

If there is no error your site is upgraded in 1.7